# Which to use: SSISDB executions and event messages versus SSIS package logging?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I know this topic is a bit general but I do have a specific use case. Does the logging utility in SSIS have any specific advantages, or additional information, over the internal logging of the SSISDB?

My environment contains packages, which are executed via the stored procs in the SSISDB. We have a separate table that tracks the executionid of each package as they are processed and reports the statuses back to the user through a web application.

I am trying to have some foresight. So far I have been monitoring the event_messages, operations and executions table in SSISDB and it has been completely sufficient in debugging and troubleshooting so far. SSISDB seems to keep track of the exact same information that SSIS logging does.

Are there any discrepancies or differences, other than the obvious data structure differences, between the SSISDB tables and SSIS package logging? Specifically, does SSIS logging have any additional information that the SSISDB *does not* record? I would rather not have to come back and update all of my SSIS packages (and sprocs, and application...) later if I can avoid it.

I'm hoping someone else has come across this scenario and has some insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started on a project a year or so ago and set up both types of logging, with the same fear you have.  I can safely say it was a complete waste of time and I only ever use the SSISDB execution reports.

I highly recommend you check out custom SSISDB logging options if you haven't already.

https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/12/22/ssis-custom-logging-levels/

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I needed! I am calling the SSISDB procs in a chain through another sproc(via table type), so I am setting parameters, synchronization etc. manually through the set_execution_parameter_value already. I will look into changing the logging levels too as needed. Thanks!